# PHP and MySQL -> displaying data

Tags: php, mysql

I have successfully accomplished my first step ([link to my G+ post](https://plus.google.com/+MaticConradi/posts/Mmg2wAyqB3r), but you don't have to read it. Everything is here). Now there are some complications. This is demo table:

```
ID | userid | Age | Name
---------------------------
 1 |  1     |  30 | John
 2 |  1     |  31 | Mike
 3 |  1     |  30 | Whoever
 4 |  2     |  32 | Jack
 5 |  2     |  31 | Alice
 6 |  3     |  30 | Kurt
```

I would like to display only rows with `userid = 1` + persons with the same age have to be in the same row:

```
userid      | Age | Name
---------------------------------
 1 (hidden) |  30 | John, Whoever
 1 (hidden) |  31 | Mike
```

In my database I'm using `subject` and `grade` instead of `age` and `name`. This is how my MySQL query looks right now:

```sql
SELECT
p.subject as 'subject'
GROUP_CONCAT(grade) as grades
FROM grades p
GROUP BY p.subject
```

This displays data for every `userid`. `Userid` isn't always 1 so I can't just say `if($userid == 1){/*code*/}else{/*code*/}` or anything similar.

How can I accomplish this?

---

Some PHP code I'm using to display data:

```
<?php
$result = $dbc->query("
SELECT
p.subject as 'subject',
id, finished, date,
GROUP_CONCAT(grade) as names
FROM grades p
GROUP BY p.subject
");
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
</tr>
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $names = split(",",$row["names"]);
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["subject"] ?> </td>
        <td><?php foreach( $names as $name){echo $name . ' ' ; } ?>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have been playing around with this and I have got it

Looks like you want to group by both user id and age so that you can perform aggregates on data which both have a specific userid and age.

I have included the code to create the table and insert the data incase anyone reading the question wanted to have a quick play.

```
create table grades
(
id int(2),
userid int(2),
age int(2),
name varchar(20),
)

insert into grades values
(1,1,30,'John'),
(2,1,31,'Mike'),
(3,1,30,'Whoever'),
(4,2,32,'Jack'),
(5,2,31,'Alice'),
(6,3,30,'Kurt');

SELECT
userid, age, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM grades
GROUP BY userid, age
```

Comment: of course for your example you can omit userid from the select clause but the output will be the same but will omit the userid column. Is this of any use?

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d9ac/3

```
SELECT Age, GROUP_CONCAT(Name)
FROM grades
WHERE userid=1
GROUP BY Age
```

Comment: Wow wish I would have known about SQL Fiddle before I answered the question I was doing it in phpmyadmin :) how horrible